# Exit and Enter on same bar

Tags: pine-script

new to Trading View and Pinescript. Trying to code entry on the close of current bar and exit on the open of next bar, then enter again on the close of the same bar and so on. This is to backtest on overnight gaps between closing price and next day opening price. Hence it would enter on the close of bar 1, then exit on the open of bar 2, enter on the close of bar 2, exit on the open of bar 3... and so on.

I have attached what I have so far. While it is exiting correctly on the open, it only enters again on the open of the next bar, whereas I would like it to enter on the close of the same bar that it exited. I also noticed that the first entry was also on the open of the second bar. **How can I both exit on the Open and re-enter on the Close of the SAME bar?**

//@version=4
strategy(title = "Buy the Close, Sell the Open", shorttitle = "gap", overlay=true)

fromYear = year > 2012
toYear = year < 2024

if close and fromYear and toYear
strategy.entry(id = "gap", long = true)

if open
strategy.close(id = "gap")

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to code entry on the close of current bar and exit on the open
> of next bar

You can do it with `strategy.exit()` with loss = 1, profit = 1 parameters
(position will be closed after one price tick after opening).

`process_orders_on_close = true` allows to enter at the close of the bar

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, process_orders_on_close = true)

if bar_index > last_bar_index - 10 
    strategy.order("Long", strategy.long)

    strategy.exit("exit", "Long", loss = 1, profit = 1)
```